# Check for substring existance in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, substring, contains

I believe there should be a duplicate question, but I just can't find it, so apologies if it is a duplicate.

I've got an array of items, and I would like to test the existence of another string.  Now to test that I know I can use:

```
if (stringArray.Any(myItem.Contains))
```

But that does not seem to work with substrings.  Is there a way to test for substrings without the use of a for-loop?

```
string[] stringArray = {"string1Item", "string2Item", "string3Item" };
//Test if "1" appears in array
if (stringArray.Any("1".Contains)) //returns false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (stringArray.Any(s => s.Contains("1")))
```

You were testing for the reverse, namely if the string `"1"` contains any of the strings in the array, which is obviously false.